# Spark Scala: Change the value of a column depending on the value of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, where-clause

I'm kind of new in Spark Scala (also in StackOv so it's a pleasure to be part of the community). There's a query that I can not perform:

I have this DF where I wish everytime column "number" has the value of "446118", the column "type" change to "P" and all the other values in type, stay the same way. This without using withColumn function. I know could be with function where but I don't know how to use where when it's about changing the value of one column depending of another one.

I would be grateful if someone help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me1cr.png)

Comment: Did you try `when(...).otherwise(...)`?

Comment: Hi! 

Yes but I can not figure it out how to make it works. I mean I don't know how to do something like:

when("number"===416118 THEN "type"===P).otherwise("type")

Comment: why do you not want to use withcolumn, it will be easy using when inside withcolumn as AminMal said

Comment: I need to do it as part of a job and they don't let me use withColumn for any reason, I solve it using withColumn as you said and it was very easy to figure it out, but I don't know hoy to solve it without using it :( @AnjaneyaTripathi